# Are the colors of the rainbow absolute or arbitrarily assigned?

Tags: visible-light

I was watching a multi-colored loading icon, and it piqued my interest.

Red, orange, yellow, green, blue, indigo, violet.
(*Is indigo a real color?  I don't know, but that's what I was told growing up*)

Is there a specific reason for the wavelengths associated with these colors?  Yellow is a color, and green is a color, and what's in between seems to be *yellow-green* or whatever name you want to call it.  But why isn't that color that lies between yellow and green what we choose to identify?  Or for any pair of adjoined colors--why are red and orange distinct colors, instead of *red-orange* and *orange-yellow*?

Is it arbitrary that we chose these spots on the spectrum to identify as red, orange, yellow, and green?  Or is there a scientific reason we chose these wavelengths?

*I have a basic understanding of the electromagnetic spectrum and visible light, but nothing more.  My apologies if I made incorrect assumptions or did not word things correctly.*

Comment: The colors are arbitrarily assigned. This question is more about visual perception and not about physics.

Comment: @Floris I mean, somewhat arbitrary, but not completely, right? I'd also argue that visual perception is part of physics, as it's the "receiving" side, and thus reflects how reality is experienced. I think the question has physical relevance.

Comment: Indigo is definitely the most arbitrary -- it's included in order to have a vowel between B and V for acronym purposes.

Comment: And even violet is not in the rainbow, it actually ends with blue.

Comment: You may be interested in the development of [color words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_term). Basically, cultures with less color words may just say "warm-cool", other cultures may say "red-yellow-cool", and so on. Still, this is culture, not physics.

Comment: In the world of art, many color names actually are the names of pigments or dyes that traditionally were used to create them.  Indigo, Ultramarine, Carmine, Vermillion, ... Indigo is the dye that is used to color blue jeans.  It has been manufactured since ancient times.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigo_dye

Comment: @rodrigo, If you look at the chart in YungHummmma's answer, you'll see that the "red" response of the human eye has a little bump at the shortest wavelengths where, it actually is higher than the "green" response.  That is the reason why the very shortest visible wavelengths have a slightly purpleish look to them.  You can see it for yourself if you shine a black-light onto a _painted_ white surface (white paper and white cotton cloth won't work because they glow brightly under UV light.  White paint usually doesn't glow.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't about physics

Comment: @JohnRennie is there a site that better suits it to which it can be moved?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing *physical* about the different visible wavelengths. Like you correctly stated, they're all fundamentally the same thing.

However, you could make the argument that there are some *biological* differences. The reason for that is that, when you see a color, it's not just a result of the wavelengths that are making it to your eye -- it's also how your eye responds to different wavelengths!

So take this diagram for example:

[image]

That shows how your different cones respond to different wavelengths.

So one answer to your question might be that, the wavelengths we choose to call the colors we do, are a result of those responses. For example, maybe we have much better resolution between colors in the blue than in the red (or vice versa, I don't know), i.e.,  two wavelengths 20nm apart look very different in one range, and pretty much the same in the other.

Comment: Wittgenstein had much to say on the question of color and whether it was the same to different people. But that is philosophy, not physics.

Comment: @JonCuster Sure, but I'm talking about even just with respect to one person -- I'm saying that if you wanted to choose a set of, say, 7 points in the visible spectrum to define as colors, there's probably an objective way to choose them, based on the (average) human eye's responsivity in the different regions, so that those points probably aren't equally spaced. And responsivity is a pretty physical question, especially with regards to detectors.

Comment: By now I just think in terms of standard laser wavelengths. Odd, perhaps, but effective...

Answer (score 0):

When Isaac Newton did his work on the phenomenon of colors produced by a prism, he was inspired to copy from the field of music, and denoted "seven colors in an octave"; the ear can actually hear several octaves, but the eye only sees one.

This somewhat forced analogy is what leads to the seven colors, ROYGBIV.

For the artistically inclined, visit http://www.webexhibits.org/colorart/bh.html.